# Java 8 streams best way to collect the records in external lists out of 2 lists

Tags: java, java-stream

I have 2 lists and want to keep only those records in the both the list based on matching property. I have implemented the FlatMap and I'm populating the external lists in conjunction with  flatmap filter condition in below way and its working fine. Can some one tell

1. if this is the right way to do
2. What are other alternatives to do this.
3. I have also added Traditional way i.e. using 2 forloops which i don't want to use as forloop has n2 complexity,

Below is the code snippet :

```
package stream;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FlatMapDemo1 {

   static Map<String, Integer> catalog = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Item> items1 = Arrays.asList(new Item(11, "item1", 1), new Item(12, "item2", 2), new Item(13, "item3", 3));
        Order order1 = new Order(1, "Order1", items1);
        List<Catalog> catalogs =  Arrays.asList(new Catalog("item1"), new Catalog("item3"), new Catalog("item5"), new Catalog(""));

        // Java Stream - is this right way to populate the external list in conjunction with filter condition? If not then how shall we do that without using 2 for loops
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Catalog> externalCatalogs =  order1.getItems().stream().flatMap(item -> catalogs.stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getName().equals(item.getName())
                        && items.add(item)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(externalCatalogs);
        System.out.println(items);

        // Using 2 For loops - i don't want to use this approach
        List<Catalog> filteredExternalCatalogs = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Item> filteredItems = new ArrayList<>();

        order1.getItems().stream().forEach(
                i -> {
                    catalogs.stream().forEach(c -> {
                        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(c.getName()) && i.getName().equals(c.getName())) {
                            filteredExternalCatalogs.add(c);
                            filteredItems.add(i);
                        }
                    });
                }
        );
        System.out.println(filteredExternalCatalogs);
        System.out.println(filteredItems);
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Order {
        int id;
        String name;
        List<Item> items;
    }
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Item {
        int id;
        String name;
        int quantity;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class Catalog {
        String name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is alternate approach for doing same thing.

```java
List<Catalog> xfilteredExternalCatalogs = new ArrayList<>();
List<Item> xfilteredItems = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> ordersList = order1.getItems().stream()
    .map(o -> o.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> catalogsList = catalogs.stream()
    .map(o -> o.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

catalogs.stream()
    .filter(p -> ordersList.contains(p.getName()))
    .forEach(c -> xfilteredExternalCatalogs.add(c));

order1.getItems().stream()
    .filter(p -> catalogsList.contains(p.getName()))
    .forEach(o -> xfilteredItems.add(o));

System.out.println(xfilteredExternalCatalogs);
System.out.println(xfilteredItems);
```